# Can I use the 1-Day CTA pass from O'Hare?

Tags: public-transport, payment-cards, chicago, ord

The Chicago "L" has a penalty fare for boarding at O'Hare airport, charging $5 instead of the ordinary $2.50. However, an unlimited day pass is available for $5. Can the unlimited day pass be purchased and used at O'Hare station?

I'm hesitant to assume it can because I don't understand why anyone would pay a single fare from O'Hare if so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, this is indeed allowed. Near its note about the $5 O'Hare fare, the [CTA Fares Page](https://www.transitchicago.com/fares/) says:

> Tip: Use an unlimited pass to board at O'Hare for no additional charge.

The same page also confirms that at O'Hare you can buy a new Ventra card and put a pass on it, or buy a disposable one- or three-day pass. (Disposable three-day passes are *only* available at the airports and must otherwise be loaded onto a Ventra card.)

[This TripAdvisor thread](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g35805-i32-k10229860-Question_about_CTA_7_day_pass_O_Hare-Chicago_Illinois.html) reaches the same conclusion, including an email from the CTA confirming that they say it is allowed.

As for why anyone would pay the $5 one-way fare instead of a day pass, the answer appears to be simply that until November 2021, [day passes cost $10](https://www.transitchicago.com/reminder-cta-fare-discounts-start-sunday/) and so there were more situations in which that was the right call.